# When I Oculus LipSync for unity on MacOS,the Error below happend

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, oculus, lipsync

I tried to use OVRLipSync on unity. I’m using MacOS now.
I got the error below. I already confirmed scripting backend is set ILCPP2.
Does someone know solutions to fix this? Please let me know if you can.

```
DllNotFoundException: OVRLipSync assembly: type: member:(null)
OVRLipSync.Initialize () (at Assets/Oculus/LipSync/Scripts/OVRLipSync.cs:267)
OVRLipSync.Awake () (at Assets/Oculus/LipSync/Scripts/OVRLipSync.cs:217)

DllNotFoundException: OVRLipSync assembly: type: member:(null)
OVRLipSync.Initialize () (at Assets/Oculus/LipSync/Scripts/OVRLipSync.cs:267)
OVRLipSync.CreateContext (System.UInt32& context, OVRLipSync+ContextProviders provider, System.Int32 sampleRate, System.Boolean enableAcceleration) (at Assets/Oculus/LipSync/Scripts/OVRLipSync.cs:309)
OVRLipSyncContextBase.Awake () (at Assets/Oculus/LipSync/Scripts/OVRLipSyncContextBase.cs:113)

OVRLipSyncContextBase.SetSmoothing: An unexpected error occured.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
OVRLipSyncContextBase:set_Smoothing (int) (at Assets/Oculus/LipSync/Scripts/OVRLipSyncContextBase.cs:69)
OVRLipSyncContextMorphTarget:Start () (at Assets/Oculus/LipSync/Scripts/OVRLipSyncContextMorphTarget.cs:110)
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be supported on Mac then?

Comment: thanks for your reply.
It's supported on Mac and I comfirmed OculusPlugin.bundle is included in Assets/Oculus/LipSync/Plugin/MacOS, but I don't know how to use that on Mac.

Comment: can you confirm the according plugins DLLs are marked to be included for the according platforms they are supposed to support via the [Inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html)? Alternatively they would need to b placed in correctly named folders so the editor would adjust those settings implicitly but that doesn't seem to be the case here

Comment: The .dll file exists in the Assets/Oculus/LipSync/Plugin/Windows folder, but when I run it under Mac OS, it refers to the .bundle file in the MacOS folder, which I believe is causing the error, but I don't know how to solve it.